# Spring boot, repository without entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository, entity

Is it possible to create a repository without an entity?
I've been working on a project and I need to take data from different tables. So I can't create an entity because I don't have that kind of table in DB.

How can I do that, Please Help?

Comment: Can you create a view in the database to aggregate all the columns you need from their respective tables?

Comment: Why then you want to use JPA? Better use https://www.jooq.org/ or Spring Data JDBC https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I cant create a view. Because I have an input from the Front-End (Input is an interval of date) that affects my data.

Comment: @CanSahin That doesn't prevent you from creating a view. That only gives you a property by which you can then filter the data from the view.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I havent heard of it. I'll check it out.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I didnt think of that. Thanks let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `aggregator`. If you know exactly which data you do need to work with, you can create a `view` with columns from those different tables and define an entity class with those column names in the view. Hence you can implement the repository just as the regular way with that entity of aggregated view.

But, if you have to fetch and combine multiple entities and you actually don't know how much varieties are there in fetching data and entities, you can write a `dao` as service or component and access different entities through different repositories and then aggregate the data programmatically as your need. You can use `native queries` too to access various data from different tables.